# Do you usually have your main Form's class own the instances of your other objects/threads?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# development.  When I create applications I typically break them up into logical classes.  For example, I have a "Map Display" program, that will display a map on the form screen.

Do you generally have the main form "own" and instantiate your other objects and threads you create for that Form?  Is this bad practice to have your Forms class own your various other classes (Map class, Pathfinding class, Other threads, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

I think the UI classes should concentrate on UI only and allow other UI 'controller' classes to own ancillary items. If the other classes are ui only and not say business logic then letting a form own them is fine, but it may limit the reusability of the form.

The [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) should be a guiding pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the MVC design pattern in this link. It has the added benefit that you can unit test some of the code used in your forms.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/napanchal/MVCDesign12052005035152AM/MVCDesign.aspx